# decorator which can add an outside method to new instances of an class

Tags: python, python-decorators, instance-methods

I have an class:

```
class Klass:
    pass
```

and an outside method:

```
def foo():
    return "foo method"
```

How to pass the test:

```
assert Klass().foo() == "foo method"
```

with decorator for `foo` method?
edited: without changes in `Klass`

Comment: If I use setattr(cls, name, function) and after that I try call MyClass().my_function(), I've got TypeError: my_function() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given. Is it a good way?

Comment: Well, that's because `self` is passed to the method/function

Comment: The solution is the decorator that @wraps your function and next setattr that wrapped function for the class which You can send in parameter of decorator. Someone sent the website with that solution in my question, but after that he deleted the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand what would you like to get by saying `decorator` but how about this?

```py
class Klass:
    
    def foo(self):
        return "foo method"

assert Klass().foo() == "foo method"
```

If this is not what are you looking for, please try to find some better words.

Comment: It is my desired result, but without changes in Klass.
I should corrent my question about this :) thanks